# How works UIViewController.addChild()

Tags: ios, swift

When i add ViewController in another view controller, i should addChild, without this, it doesn't work

```
@objc func openMenuHandler() {
        let menuController = MenuController()
        menuController.view.frame = CGRect(x: -menuWidth, y: 0, width: menuWidth, height: self.view.frame.height)
        
        let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first
        keyWindow?.addSubview(menuController.view)
        
        addChild(menuController) // I should add this line to display UITableViewController properly
}
```

But if i initialize UITableViewController in class scope, it works **without** addChild method

```
    let menuController = MenuController() // this line in UIViewController class scope


    @objc func openMenuHandler() {
        self.menuController.view.frame = CGRect(x: -menuWidth, y: 0, width: menuWidth, height: self.view.frame.height)
        
        let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first
        keyWindow?.addSubview(self.menuController.view)
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Can you describe what happens?

Comment: @Sweeper so, my UITableViewController is visible, and i can change background for example. But content (cells) not shown. But if i add method addChild, that shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.addChild(menuController)` adds `menuController` into the `self.children` array (it also does other things, but this is what causes the behaviour in your question).

By declaring `menuController` as a local variable, the `MenuController` object will be deallocated once the `openMenuHandler` method returns, because no other object is holding a strong reference to that object. If you do `self.addChild(menuController)`, however, the object will be added to the `self.children` array, which means now `self` is holding a reference to the `MenuController` object (via the `children` array), so now it won't be deallocated.

Declaring `menuController` outside the method has the same effect in terms of holding references. Now `self` holds a reference to the object via the `menuController` property.

I still recommend you to use `addChild` though, because it seems like you are showing a menu, which semantically is a "child" of whatever VC it is displayed from. As I said at the start, `addChild` does other things too, and those other things might be useful to you, such as making `menuController.parent` equal to `self`.

Answer (score 2):

By the way, beyond the simple “make sure that the child view controller isn't deallocated”, `addChild` has a deeper purpose, ensuring that the view controller in question is added to the view controller hierarchy, as part of the “view controller containment” API. The ensures that various appearance related methods are called on the child view controller (e.g. `viewDidAppear`, rotation events, etc.). As [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller) says, view controller containment calls, “allows iOS to properly route events to child view controllers and the views those controllers manage.”

---

By the way, the correct sequence is to:

- [`addChild`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621394-addchild) of the child view controller to the parent view controller’s children;
- add the child view controller’s view to the view hierarchy of its parent; and
- call [`child.didMove(toParent:self)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621405-didmove) to tell the child that it has been added to the parent’s view controller.

---

If you have to remove the child view, the sequence is:

- call [`child.willMove(toParent: nil)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621381-willmove) to tell the child that it will be removed from the parent’s view controller.
- remove the child view controller’s view from the view hierarchy of its parent; and
- Call [`removeFromParent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621425-removefromparent) on the child view controller to finish the process.